# Scheduled Jobs and Time Change

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

We have some scheduled jobs that run every day at various times of the day.  These jobs include logging their results like this:

```
<cflog file="#logname#"  text="START #logname#">
<cfoutput>#mid(now(),6,19)# Scheduled Jobs running on Production (#server.Name#)
```

This past weekend, when the clocks were advanced one hour, all these jobs ran one hour late.  Here is some sample output from the above two lines from a job that runs at 00:05 each day.  First, just before the time change.

```
"Information","jrpp-213","03/10/13","00:05:00",,"START scheduledjobs_0005"
"Information","jrpp-213","03/10/13","00:05:00",,"start sheduledjobs_0005"
```

Next, the first time after the time change.  It runs one hour later.

```
 "Information","jrpp-343","03/11/13","01:05:00",,"START scheduledjobs_0005"
 "Information","jrpp-343","03/11/13","01:05:00",,"start sheduledjobs_0005"
```

Then the following day it's back to normal.

```
"Information","jrpp-111","03/12/13","00:05:00",,"START scheduledjobs_0005"
"Information","jrpp-111","03/12/13","00:05:00",,"start sheduledjobs_0005"
```

Files produced by these jobs were also timestamped one hour later than when the job was scheduled to run.

Has anyone seen anything similar?  Does anyone know what would cause this or how to prevent it?  We are running Version  9,0,1,274733.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Operating System  Windows 2003    
OS Version  5.2

Comment: The time was modified before the time change actually took place is the only explanation I can think of.  I wouldn't be too concerned with a timestamp unless the data in the file is incorrect.  Does the data in the file reflect the same data as if the job had ran at 00:05?  Verify your data is bad before getting too upset.

Comment: @JustAguy, I don't understand what you mean by the time being modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this before. The scheduler calculates the next run of a daily task by adding 24 hours to the scheduled start time. In this case, adding 24 hours to 00:00 ST on Sunday puts the next start time at 01:05 DST on Monday. The scheduler corrects itself the next day because it adds 24 hours to the scheduled start time, which is now 00:00 DST.

It's important to handle it this way, because if someone had scheduled a task to run during the missing hour, the task wouldn't run at all on that day. Furthermore, if the task was scheduled to run during the extra hour in the fall, it would actually run twice.

Comment: Makes sense.  Any suggestions on how to force it to stick to the actual time of day?

Comment: I'm not sure there's an out-of-the-box way to force that with the scheduler. But you could have your process update the scheduled task itself after each run. So instead of setting it to running daily, it would run once and at the end, it would calculate the next run and use CFSCHEDULE to add it to the scheduler. 

Something like `if current hour is not equal to current hour + 24 hours, adjust by 1; else, schedule for now + 24 hours.`

Kind of a clunky hack. Is the timing of the task considered mission critical?

Comment: The tasks that are scheduled are containers for other jobs.  There are 6 container jobs that contain over a hundred individual jobs.  Two of the individual jobs produce files that are picked up by unix cronjobs.  When the unix jobs ran, the files were not there so we had to do extra work to recover.

Comment: Sounds mission critical to me. I'd suggest creating a babysitter scheduled task that verifies the container jobs will run at the correct times. If the hour part of the start time is off, adjust it. Set the babysitter job to run a couple hours before the actual jobs are set to run, to ensure the time gap from DST doesn't prevent it from running soon enough. Or, as I mentioned above, you can have each task reschedule itself at the end of the current run. Check the hour part of the current hour + 24 hours. If they're different, adjust the schedule for the next run accordingly.